# Filling NA by copying content of other rows in R

Tags: r, duplicates, na

i have a data set that resembles the table below. what i want to do is replace the NA for each ID with the available data in that respective ID apart for the outcome variable which i want to predict for. eg for ID 1, i want copy information from year 1990 to 1991, 1992, 1993. for ID 2, i should copy information from year 1992 to 1990, 1991 and 1993. The ID represents a cluster, say village. eventually i want to predict the outcome for the missing years. i want to do this in R.

```
   ID YeStart Author YEAR   Lat    Long Outome
     1    1990  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718     20
     1    1991   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     30
     1    1992   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     1    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     2    1990   <NA>   NA    NA      NA      2
     2    1991   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     2    1992 Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718     NA
     2    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1990   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1991 Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718     NA
     3    1992   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     50
```

Comment: Hey @jonestats, you still haven't accepted the answers to your earlier questions. Take a second and figure that out. You just click the check mark next to the answer you want to accept.

Comment: let me check and do that now. i ticked a yes yesterday to indicate it was useful and i cant find that option again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is somewhere on the site already. But you can do it with the functions `merge` and `complete.cases`.

```
d <- read.table(text="ID YeStart Author YEAR   Lat    Long Outome
     1    1990  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718     20
     1    1991   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     30
     1    1992  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718     NA
     1    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     2    1990   <NA>   NA    NA      NA      2
     2    1991   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     2    1992 Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718     NA
     2    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1990   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1991 Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718     NA
     3    1992   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     NA
     3    1993   <NA>   NA    NA      NA     50", header=TRUE)

d1 <- d[c('ID', 'YeStart', 'Outome')]
d2 <- d[! names(d) %in% c('Outome', 'YeStart')]
merge(d1, unique(d2[complete.cases(d2), ]))

#    ID YeStart Outome Author YEAR   Lat    Long
# 1   1    1990     20  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718
# 2   1    1991     30  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718
# 3   1    1992     NA  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718
# 4   1    1993     NA  Goroo 2012 23.45 -16.718
# 5   2    1990      2 Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718
# 6   2    1991     NA Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718
# 7   2    1992     NA Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718
# 8   2    1993     NA Berthe 2012 20.45 -16.718
# 9   3    1990     NA Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718
# 10  3    1991     NA Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718
# 11  3    1992     NA Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718
# 12  3    1993     50 Berthe 2012 40.45 -16.718
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this it works out perfectly. where can learn some of these things. do you know of any reference that can be useful to me.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there. A good place to start is Hadley Wickham's R vocabulary sheet (https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/vocabulary). After that, I'd recommend reading Patrick Burns' book "R Inferno". It's free, just google it.

Comment: hi, i realized that if a cluster has data in more than 2 years, then it is duplicated twice. eg if cluster 1 has data in 1990 and 1992, then when i fill in the cases i will have 8 cluster 1 data points instead of the normal 4, so that i have 2 1990,2 1991, 2 1992 and 2 1993. if its for 3 years, then it gives 12 points. how can i get around this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved. Thanks too for the materials to read. i invest some time to go through them thoroughly. I really appreciate ur support.